# tinymce adjust height and button height of toolbar

Tags: css, tinymce

How can i adjust the style of the toolbar of TinyMCE? I want a smaller toolbar, with smaller buttons. So the height of the buttons and toolbar has to be adjusted. Also i want to remove the border around the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [editor_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3aeditor_css) setting of tinymce.